# Kotlin Coroutines' utilisation of IO threads

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I need to understand that if I have a single IO thread in a system, I run a multiple IO operations on multiple coroutines, can those coroutines use the very same thread in a suspended manner (meaning when coroutine A is waiting for IO result, coroutine B can utilise that thread for its IO operation) or the Thread will be blocked by the first IO operation?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what kind of IO operation you are doing. If you are doing an *asynchronous* IO operation, then this IO operation does not block the thread and let other coroutines use it. If you are doing a *blocking* IO operation, then it blocks the thread and other coroutines cannot use it.

Comment: So if I have got it correctly, if I invoke a plain blocking function from inside a coroutine, this invocation will block the Thread the coroutine is running in, and if I change that same blocking function to a suspended one, then this coroutine will be suspended and Thread is free to execute other work. Right?

Comment: Beware that just declaring a function `suspend` makes no difference. You'd have to switch to another IO library, one which supports making async requests.

Comment: "Beware that just declaring a function suspend makes no difference"
Agreed, thanks for explicitly mentioning it.

Comment: By the way, in my first comment, I intended to use withContext{ } or async{ } etc.